# Filter rows from subsets of a Pandas DataFrame efficiently

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filtering, data-manipulation

I have a DataFrame consisting of medical data where the columns are ["Patient_ID", "Code", "Data"], where "Code" just represents some medical interaction patient "Patient_ID" had on "Date". Any patient will generally have more than one row, since they have more than one interaction. I want to apply two types of filtering to this data.

1. Remove any patients who have less than some `min_len` interactions
2. To each patient apply a half-overlapping, sliding window of length `T` days. Within each window keep only the first of any duplicate codes, and then shuffle the codes within the window

So I need to modify subsets of the overall dataframe, but the modification involves changing the size of the subset. I have both of these implemented as part of a larger pipeline, however they are a sigfnificant bottleneck in terms of time. I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to achieve the same thing, as I really just threw together what worked and I'm not too familiar on efficiency of pandas operations. Here is how I have them currently:

```py
def Filter_by_length(df, min_len = 1):
    print("Filtering short sequences...")
    df = df.sort_values(axis = 0, by = ['ID', 'DATE']).copy(deep = True)
    new_df = []
    for sub_df in tqdm((df[df.ID == sub] for sub in df.ID.unique()), total = len(df.ID.unique()), miniters = 1):
        if len(sub_df) >= min_len:
            new_df.append(sub_df.copy(deep = True))
    if len(new_df) != 0:
        df =  pd.concat(new_df, sort = False)
    else:
        df = pd.DataFrame({})
    print("Done")
    return df
```

```py
def shuffle_col(df, col):
    df[col] = np.random.permutation(df[col])
    return df

def Filter_by_redundancy(df, T, min_len = 1):
    print("Filtering redundant concepts and short sequences...")
    df = df.sort_values(axis = 0, by = ['ID', 'DATE']).copy(deep = True)
    new_df = []
    for sub_df in tqdm((df[df.ID == sub] for sub in df.ID.unique()), total = len(df.ID.unique()), miniters = 1):
        start_date = sub_df.DATE.min()
        end_date = sub_df.DATE.max()
        next_date = start_date + dt.timedelta(days = T)
        while start_date <= end_date:
            sub_df = pd.concat([sub_df[sub_df.DATE < start_date],\
                                shuffle_col(sub_df[(sub_df.DATE <= next_date) & (sub_df.DATE >= start_date)]\
                                            .drop_duplicates(subset = ['CODE']), "CODE"),\
                                sub_df[sub_df.DATE > next_date]], sort = False )
            start_date += dt.timedelta(days = int(T/2))
            next_date += dt.timedelta(days = int(T/2))
        if len(sub_df) >= min_len:
            new_df.append(sub_df.copy(deep = True))
    if len(new_df) != 0:
        df =  pd.concat(new_df, sort = False)
    else:
        df = pd.DataFrame({})
    print("Done")
    return df
```

As you can see, in the second case I am actually applying both filters, because it is important to have the option to apply both together or either one on its own, but I am interested in any performance improvement that can be made to either one or both.

Comment: Get the group lengths by `df.groupby('id').size()`, then just remove any ID with insufficient length. I'm not sure what your other section altogether does, but you also can replace any time you say `for sub_df in [df[df['id'] == i] for i in df['id'].unique()]` with `for id, sub_df in df.groupby('id')`

Comment: This approach for length is much faster, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, instead of counting in your group-by like that, I would use this approach:

```
>>> d = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'q': [np.random.randint(1, 15, size=np.random.randint(1, 5)) for _ in range(5)]}).explode('q')
   id   q
0   1   1
0   1   9
1   2   9
1   2  10
1   2   4
2   3   3
2   3   6
2   3   2
2   3  10
3   4  11
3   4   5
4   5   5
4   5   6
4   5   3
4   5   2

>>> sizes = d.groupby('id').size()
>>> d[d['id'].isin(sizes[sizes >= 3].index)]  # index is list of IDs meeting criteria
   id   q
1   2   9
1   2  10
1   2   4
2   3   3
2   3   6
2   3   2
2   3  10
4   5   5
4   5   6
4   5   3
4   5   2
```

I'm not sure why you want to shuffle your codes within some window. To avoid an X-Y problem, what are you in fact trying to do there?

Comment: I will give the first approach a try, thanks. The idea of the shuffling is that overall the sequential nature of the data is important, but within some time window the order is arbitrary. As a simplest example if a patient is prescribed 3 medications on the same day then the order if not significant for those 3. This is an implementation of work from a paper too, not something I have decided to do myself. It is certainly possible that the shuffling ends up being pointless.